# Python Pyodbc cursor.execute functions executes 2 times, why?

Tags: python, sql, openpyxl, pyodbc

My code is trying to update tables on sql from .xls files directly.
At the moment it takes hours to complete the process.
I'm using python.

```
    for row in range(2, (sheet.max_row + 1),1):
      frame = sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value[:20] if sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value is not None else None
      planta = sheet.cell(row=row, column=2).value
      sp_value = sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).value[:10] if sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).value is not None else None
      pestaña = sheet.cell(row=row, column=4).value[:20] if sheet.cell(row=row, column=4).value is not None else None
      para_Impresion = sheet.cell(row=row, column=5).value
      ic_caption = sheet.cell(row=row, column=6).value[:40] if sheet.cell(row=row, column=6).value is not None else None
      ii_caption = sheet.cell(row=row, column=7).value[:40] if sheet.cell(row=row, column=7).value is not None else None
      ii_caption_2 = sheet.cell(row=row, column=8).value[:30] if sheet.cell(row=row, column=8).value is not None else None
      ie_short_desc = sheet.cell(row=row, column=9).value[:30] if sheet.cell(row=row, column=9).value is not None else None
      pr_short_desc = sheet.cell(row=row, column=10).value[:10] if sheet.cell(row=row, column=10).value is not None else None
      iivalue = sheet.cell(row=row, column=11).value[:450] if sheet.cell(row=row, column=11).value is not None else None
      info_field_type = sheet.cell(row=row, column=12).value[:30] if sheet.cell(row=row, column=12).value is not None else None
      
      query=("INSERT INTO "+basededatos1+".[dbo].[$Dicc_Valores Predefinidos] (FRAME, Planta, SP_VALUE, Pestaña, Para_Impresion, IC_CAPTION, II_CAPTION, II_CAPTION_2, IE_SHORT_DESC, PR_SHORT_DESC, IIVALUE, [INFO FIELD TYPE]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
      cursor.execute(query, 
                     frame, planta, sp_value, pestaña, para_Impresion, ic_caption, ii_caption, ii_caption_2, ie_short_desc, pr_short_desc, iivalue, info_field_type)
      print(cursor.messages)
```

On my query execution, the moment I did the debug, that line (cursor.execute) is executing two times, there is no clear reason why the program is doing this.

I have try debugging and changing the structure of the code and checking the output of the query with cursor.messages but nothing helps.